# Timer in android java

Tags: java, android, timer, android-timer

I have  2 activity in activity2  i have  a timer when activity create timer is started in activity on_Destroy i put timer_task.cancel(); but  When opened the activity2  for the second time  is create new timer task and not Canceled or destroyed the last timer  and 2 timer is while be run in one  activity

my code

```
    private  TimerTask mTimerTask;
private void doTimerTask(){
    nCounter = 4;

    qtimer.setMax(20);

    if(mTimerTask!=null) {
        mTimerTask.cancel();
    }

    mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.d("Timerrrr",nCounter+"");
                    if(nCounter<1){
                        Finished();
                    }else {
                        qtimer.setProgress(nCounter);
                        nCounter--;
                    }
                }
            });
        }};

    // public void schedule (TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
    t.schedule(mTimerTask, 0, 1000);  //

}

private void stopTask() {

    if (mTimerTask != null) {
        Log.d("nCounter canceled",nCounter+"");
        mTimerTask.cancel();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mTimerTask.cancel();
    MainActivity.this.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
public void stopTimerTask(View v) {       
    //stop the timer, if it's not already null
    if (mTimerTask != null) {
        mTimerTask.cancel();
        mTimerTask = null;
    }
}
```

And Where do u call your `stopTask()` method?

And I suggest don't put `mTimerTask.cancel();` in `onDestroy()`, but put it in `onStop()`.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks

  I used this before, but it is not working.

When the activity is destroyed, the timer is also stopped, but when the activity is called for the second time

 Timer initialized twice

Comment: did you also try with putting in onStop()?

Comment: yes i put it in (onstop, onDestroy, onPressBack) , i used System.exit(0) and is worked  but is not true way